# How to solve a "permission denied" error on git bash?

Tags: pip, git-bash

I am using git bash to run my python program, but unfortunately more recently when trying to install some modules using git bash, I get a "permission denied" error.

Here is an example:

```
$ pip install mysql-connector-python.
bash: /c/Users/user/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/pip: **Permission denied**
```

Comment: try to run as administrator i.e the git bash app.

Answer (score 0):

Click the Start icon and click in the Search box.
Type git bash into the search box. You will see the git bash in the search window.
Hover the mouse over the git bash program and right-click.
Select "Run as administrator".
after that run  "pip install mysql-connector-python" command